# Input and 2 buttons in one line & input width = auto

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a search box and two buttons next to it (Add & Upload) to be displayed in a single line in md devices and bigger.

As you can see in the image below, if I use "col-md-auto", the search box stretches a lot and pushes both buttons to the line below. I would like it to be stretched as much as possible (width:auto), while leaving both buttons in the same line.

[image]

In smaller devices, I want the search box to be displayed in one line (width:100%) and the two other buttons in another one.

This is the code I've been playing with to no avail:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <div class="input-group searchbox">
        <input type="text" id="search" name="searchtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col searchbox">
    <button type="button" name="btn-addtext" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add text</button>
    <button type="file" name="btn-upload" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload text</button>
  </div>
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `col-12` for the `div` that's why it stretched to the whole row.

*Try this:*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-10 col-sm-10 col-md-auto">
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <div class="input-group searchbox">
        <input type="text" id="search" name="searchtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 searchbox">
    <button type="button" name="btn-addtext" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add text</button>
    <button type="file" name="btn-upload" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload text</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That almost did the job, except that in md and bigger screens, there is still a big empty space between the search box and the two buttons. I would like the search box to stretch as much as possible., without pushing the two buttons to the line below (which now is not happening thanks to your help).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the whole grid size to this div here `<div class="col-12 col-md-auto">` which should be updated, see below example.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-8 col-md-auto">
    <form class="" action="" method="post">
      <div class="input-group searchbox">
        <input type="text" id="search" name="searchtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col searchbox">
    <button type="button" name="btn-addtext" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add text</button>
    <button type="file" name="btn-upload" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload text</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Still not working. This is how it looks in small screens: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7glbwnhizsrm6l/searchbox2.jpg?dl=0

Comment: And in bigger screens: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9g5u8rvubty2z7m/searchbox3.jpg?dl=0 You can see there is a space in the right. The buttons should be aligned to the right and the search box should stretch to occupy the rest.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not able to access the url, can you post the images here: https://imgur.com and share

Comment: @PabloCastagnino just use `col-xs-6` instead of `col-xs-8`. Just set the grid size according to different screen sizes.